# From SWIFT Playground to custom View (IBDesignable?)

Tags: xcode, swift

### Question:

I've written a custom View Component in a playground but I can't figure out how to turn it into a custom class that I can use in the Interface Builder.  Specifically, I'm confused as to how to make sure my custom view will resize correctly as the IB view is changed

#### Sub Question

- I would also like to  be able to use the **@IBDesignable/@IBInspectable** functionality as well if possible

### Playground Code

```
import UIKit
let labelWidth : CGFloat = 200.0
var viewWidth  : CGFloat = 200.0
let labelHeight: CGFloat = 60.0
var viewHeight : CGFloat = 60.0

let xOffset : CGFloat = 20
let yOffset : CGFloat = 20


let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0 + 10, labelWidth, 50))

label.text = "Custom Text"


label.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
label.layer.masksToBounds = true
//label.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

label

let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,labelWidth,20))
titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: label.font.fontName, size: 10)
titleLabel.text = "  TITLE"
titleLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
titleLabel

let v = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight))

v.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
v.addSubview(label)
v.addSubview(titleLabel)

v.layer.borderWidth = 1
v.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor

v
```

### Playground Visual Output

[image]

*Note: Obviously these are not the final colors i want to use but they help differentiate the components*

Answer (score 1):

I just posted this answer for a similar question.

Here is a sample class to get you started.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class MyTabView: UIView {
    @IBInspectable tabTitle: String = ""
    @IBInspectable tabColor: UIColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        // Initialization code
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        // stuff for interface builder only
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
    {
        // this is where your view gets drawed
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

Note: you only need to override drawRect if you need custom drawing.